# React Navigation - TopTabNavigator inside DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-navigation

react-navigation: 3.2.1

I've create TopTabNavigator (using createMaterialTopTabNavigator) inside a Drawer (using createDrawerNavigator).

Swiping navigates between tabs but the first time I swipe from the direction of the drawer - the drawer will be the only thing that will open / close. 
swiping between the tabs is stopped (click the buttons in the bar still works).

What can cause that?

```
const MainTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator ({
        Tab1: {
            screen: Tab1Screen,
        },
        Tab2: {
            screen: Tab2Screen,
        },
    });

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
    Main: {
        screen: MainTab,
    }
);
```

Adding [link for Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@chenop/toptabnavigator-inside-drawernavigator) - but unfortunately there is a [bug](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5259#issuecomment-440596789) when using createDrawerNavigation inside expo.snack.io

Comment: Is it possible to quickly add up the problem in snack.expo.io? Easy to debug and understand the issue.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu Unfortunately there is a bug using createDrawerNavigation inside snack.expo.io... https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5259#issuecomment-440596789